# change the date_format of an API value in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to change the date format in

```
print("<td class='month subscriber subscriber-fixed-alone fixed-cell'>$date</td>");
```

which prints `$date` as **2017-12**. How would I change this to **December 2017**?

I have tried

```
print("<td class='month subscriber subscriber-fixed-alone fixed-cell'>" . date_format($date, 'F Y') . "</td>");
```

but I get no value. The value is pulled from an HTTP API by

```
foreach ($content as $dates => $row) {
$date = $dates;
```

Think I am missing something rather simple.

Comment: Sorry if it is. I searched for a while on this problem and didn't come across any articles that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print("<td class='month subscriber subscriber-fixed-alone fixed-cell'>".date('F Y',strtotime($date))."</td>");
```

Comment: Cheers, this worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$originalDate = "2017-12";
$newDate = date("F Y", strtotime($originalDate));

echo $newDate;
```

Comment: Thank you. Just one question so I understand it. If the `$originalDate` value changes per request from the API. This would always show 2017-12, right?

Comment: it just a example how can you convert you date.You have to update your date value as per the api value

Comment: I thought so, just wondered if I hadn't understood it. Thank you again.